# Does the fastai library automatically infer text and label from header?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, fast-ai

I have dataframe object which has two fields i.e. text and label and I want to do text classification similar to ULMFit

Here are codes for that with the specific purpose below

```
data_lm = TextLMDataBunch.from_df(train_df = df_trn, valid_df = df_val, path = "")

# Language model learner object

data_clas = TextClasDataBunch.from_df(path = "", train_df = df_trn, valid_df = df_val, vocab=data_lm.train_ds.vocab, bs=32)
```

classification object

```
learn = language_model_learner(data_lm, AWD_LSTM, drop_mult=0.5)

# learn language model object

learn.fit_one_cycle(10, 1e-2)

# Fit a language model

learn.save_encoder('good_ft_enc')

# save the encoder of the language model

learn = text_classifier_learner(data_clas,AWD_LSTM,drop_mult=0.7)

learn.load_encoder('good_ft_enc')

# classifier object with the loaded encoder

learn.fit_one_cycle(3, 1e-2)

# fit the classifier
```

These are the series of steps followed , but I am not able to understand if the dataloader has loaded my text and label field properly because I have not given them anywhere in the function arguments. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The [datablock](https://docs.fast.ai/text.data.html#TextDataBunch.from_df) API is a fundamental building block to the recent fastai 1.0+

Therefore, either `TextLMDataBunch.from_df` (or `TextClasDataBunch.from_df`) doing several things on your behalf including defining torch dataset, creating labels, splitting them into train/test etc.

I highly encourage you to go over the datablock docs

https://docs.fast.ai/data_block.html#The-data-block-API